# Laravel Form Request Validation rule "required" not working with null values

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-validation

I have Laravel/Vue application and I'm submiting form with file and some other data using axios.

```
  this.loading = true;
  this.errors = {};

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('type', this.type);
  formData.append('file', this.file);
  formData.append('date', this.date);

  axios.post(`/file-upload`,
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.loading = false;
          // Success..
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        if (error.response.status === 422) { // Laravel XHR Requests errors
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

In Laravel controller I have store method with form request validator

```
public function store(ImportRequest $request)
{
   // Request is valid..
}
```

ImportRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'type' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx|file|max:512',
        'date' => 'required|date',
    ];
}
```

In my vue component default field values is null. And when I submitting empty form I'm expecting that validation will fail and return messages that fields are required but only errors I get is about file mimes, size and date. Nothing about required...

[Request Headers Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R6uQ.png)

From Laravel documentation I understand that required rule must return error.
"A field is considered "empty" if one of the following conditions are true: The value is null..."
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required

For now only solution I think of is in javascript check values against null and only if not null add to FormData. In that case required rule works as I expect

Any ideas? Em I doing something wrong?

**UPDATED | SOLVED**

null is considered as string "null"

[image: dd() request result]

Comment: in `rules()` are you able to `dd` the request to check the request data coming into the validator?

Comment: yeah, if you dd() the request values, you will see that null is a string not `Null` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null is considered as a text `'null'` wich validate the required condition (there is no `Null` in http form values.

What laravel consider `Null` is an empty value in postman.
To be more precise, there is a middleware that switches empty value into `Null` values. You can disable it in kernel.php if you need the empty value to stay empty.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. null is considered as string.